# Python regular expression newline escape character

Tags: python, regex

I'm a bit confused about Python's regular expression. Specifically, why doesn't the following line return `True`?

Code:`bool(re.search(r'ab\n^c$', 'ab\nc'))`

Comment: `^` and `$` have special meaning in regular expressions. I suggest you do some research on regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`$` matches the end of the string, so `c` must be at the end. Your matched string ends in `c$` however. Next, you also included `^`, which matches the *start* of a string, but you put it in the middle of the expression.

Either escape `^` and `$` so they match *literals*, or make `^` match the start of *each line in the text* with the [`re.MULTILINE` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), and remove `^` and `$` from the text to match.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> bool(re.search(r'ab\n\^c\$', 'ab\n^c$'))  # escaped
True
>>> # multiline and target text adjusted
...
>>> bool(re.search(r'ab\n^c$', 'ab\nc', flags=re.MULTILINE)) 
True
```

Comment: Thanks. But I also tried this line: bool(re.search(r'ab\n^c$', 'ab\nc')), and the result is still False.. Why is that? I mean, the second line in the string is just a single 'c' and it should be matched, right?

Comment: I address that in my answer already. `^` matches the *absolute start*, not the start of every line, unless you specifically switch behaviour with the `re.MULTILINE` flag.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: A `^` after `\n` is redundant, as there is text after `\n`. `r'(?m)ab\n^c$'` = `r'(?m)ab\nc$'`